# Django cleaned form data as list instead of string

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with a multiple select field, e.g.:

```
FRUIT_CHOICES = (
('apple', 'apple'),
('orange', 'orange'),
)
fruits = forms.CharField(label='fruit type', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=FRUIT_CHOICES))
```

When a user checks both 'apples' and 'oranges' and submits the form, and the form is validated, it produces a string, which is formatted to look like a list:

```
form.is_valid()
type(form.cleaned_data['fruits'])
>>> <class 'str'>
print(form.cleaned_data['fruits'])
>>> ['apple', 'orange']
```

Now if I want to use the values 'apple' and 'orange' in my view, i'll have to create some type of regex to remove them from the string. This seems like a cumbersome solution. If there a way to get this data as a list straight from the form object?

Answer (score 2):

`forms.CharField` isn't a suitable field for selcting multiple options. You can use [`forms.MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) instead.

```
fruits = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='fruit type', choices=FRUIT_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

If this is a model form and you are saving to the database it gets trickier, because if you save a list to a `models.CharField` you'll get a string like `"['apple', 'orange']"`, which is similar to your original problem. You might find a library like [`django-multiselectfield`](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) useful.

Comment: The widget disappears from the template when I use MultpleChoiceField. Any idea why ?

Comment: When you switch to `MultipleChoiceField` you should still specify the widget. I've updated the answer.